# excel vba macro to import information from one book to another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have 2 workbooks book 1 and book 2.

Book 1 has 3 filled columns.

1. Line number
2. Style number
3. PO number

[image]

Book 2 has 2 filled columns.

1. Style number
2. PO number

[image]

At first I was importing the information, band number, from book 1 to book 2, by comparing style number of both books.

When the style number from both books match then the band number from book 1 is imported to book 2.

This is the code:

```
Sub procedure2()
Dim key As Variant, oCell As Range, i&, z%
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Dic2 As Object: Set Dic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


    'source
    Set w1 = Workbooks("book1.xlsm").Worksheets(1)

    'destination
    Set w2 = Workbooks("book2.xlsm").Worksheets(1)

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'get the last row for w1
    i = w1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' fill dictionary with data for searching
    For Each oCell In w1.Range("C2:C" & i)
        'row number for duplicates
        z = 1: While Dic.exists(oCell.Value & "_" & z): z = z + 1: Wend
        'add data with row number to dictionary
        If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value & "_" & z) Then
            Dic.Add oCell.Value & "_" & z, oCell.Offset(, -2).Value
        End If
    Next
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'get the last row for w2
    i = w2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'fill "B" with results
    For Each oCell In w2.Range("D2:D" & i)
        'determinate row number for duplicated values
        z = 1: While Dic2.exists(oCell.Value & "_" & z): z = z + 1: Wend
        'search
        For Each key In Dic
            If oCell.Value & "_" & z = key Then
                oCell.Offset(, -2).Value = Dic(key)
            End If
        Next
        'correction of the dictionary in case
        'when sheet "A" has less duplicates than sheet "B"
        If oCell.Offset(, -2).Value = "" Then
            Dic2.RemoveAll: z = 1
            For Each key In Dic
                If oCell.Value & "_" & z = key Then
                    oCell.Offset(, -2).Value = Dic(key)
                End If
            Next
        End If
        'add to dictionary already passed results for
        'the next duplicates testing
        If Not Dic2.exists(oCell.Value & "_" & z) Then
            Dic2.Add oCell.Value & "_" & z, ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It works succesfully.

**But now i want to import the information, band number, by comparing both the style number and PO numbers contained in book 1 and book 2.**

**If style numbers of both books match and PO numbers of both books match then the information, the related band number should be imported.**

**How do i modify the code in order to do this?**

Comment: is Band Number and Line Number the same thing?

Comment: @assylias, I think that they are the same by looking at the header: Line No (book1 - column A) and Line Number (book2 - column B)

Comment: Why not just use a VLOOKUP? Seems a much simpler way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for, I hope?
You need to match both columns so take both columns to the dictionary.

```
'.......
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
'get the last row for w1
i = w1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
' fill dictionary with data for searching
For Each oCell In w1.Range("C2:C" & i)
    'row number for duplicates
    z = 1: While Dic.exists(oCell.Value & "_" & oCell.Offset(, 3).Value & "_" & z): z = z + 1: Wend
    'add data with row number to dictionary
    If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value & "_" & oCell.Offset(, 3).Value & "_" & z) Then
        Dic.Add oCell.Value & "_" & oCell.Offset(, 3).Value & "_" & z, oCell.Offset(, -2).Value
    End If
Next
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
'get the last row for w2
i = w2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
'fill "B" with results
For Each oCell In w2.Range("D2:D" & i)
    'determinate row number for duplicated values
    z = 1: While Dic2.exists(oCell.Value & "_" & oCell.Offset(, 3).Value & "_" & z): z = z + 1: Wend
    'search
    For Each key In Dic
        If oCell.Value & "_" & oCell.Offset(, 3).Value & "_" & z = key Then
            oCell.Offset(, -2).Value = Dic(key)
        End If
    Next
    'correction of the dictionary in case
    'when sheet "A" has less duplicates than sheet "B"
    If oCell.Offset(, -2).Value = "" Then
        Dic2.RemoveAll: z = 1
        For Each key In Dic
            If oCell.Value & "_" & oCell.Offset(, 3).Value & "_" & z = key Then
                oCell.Offset(, -2).Value = Dic(key)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'add to dictionary already passed results for
    'the next duplicates testing
    If Not Dic2.exists(oCell.Value & "_" & oCell.Offset(, 3).Value & "_" & z) Then
        Dic2.Add oCell.Value & "_" & oCell.Offset(, 3).Value & "_" & z, ""
    End If
Next
```

Btw, when I tested your code:

```
Set w1 = Workbooks("book1.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
```

It gave me an error. Should it be like this? and same for w2

```
Set w1 = Workbooks.open(FULL_PATH_TO_WORKBOOK).Worksheets(1)
```

where FULL_PATH_TO_WORKBOOK can be obtained by

```
Thisworkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & "book1.xlsm"
```

if you put the macros in book1

Answer (score 0):

If new code isn't mandatory you could just rerun this Sub, compare the PO number this time and then delete those rows where the comparison doesn't fit.